# what point do c libraries get linked

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, malloc

Let's say I redefine malloc e.g. in a memory debugging program electric fence. electric fence says that one must link the library with the gcc -g -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -lefence test.c. So my understanding is that if gcc does not find the symbols in any of the libraries then it looks into the C libraries. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and to understand what `gcc` is actually doing, and how does it starts the linker `ld` which does the real work of linking, you can pass the `-v` flag to `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct: the linker tries to resolve symbols using the libraries explicitly passed as parameters first, then it's looking up symbols in the C standard libraries.